# how ngResource cache works in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

How does the ngResource cache works in angularjs? if the cache data is already cache does the ngresource will hit/call the api? 
I need to cache the read-only list so that when the use call it again it will look to the cache.

Comment: It uses the built in http cache which caches based on the URL. What do you need to know specifically? Are you having a problem getting it to work?

Comment: I use ngResource, i just like to know how does the caching works. for example, because i want to make sure that if i call the api then cache it, it will never call the api again if it has already cache.

Comment: If you're requesting the same URL and have cache enabled, the result will be cached. Unless there's a bug in it, or something else unforeseen, of course. Your own testing will tell you whether or not the solution is viable for your use case